# EF core navigation properties prevent auto loading on add

Tags: entity-framework-core

Does anyone knows if we can prevent the loading of navigation properties when calling Entity.Add. I checked the source code of EF core and it seems that when TraverseGraph is called (when calling Add) in its internal API it is loading all navigation properties. Is there a way to customize this behavior in order not to load a navigation property in Add. We want to set only the Id int field of the foreign key without loading the Instance of the navigation property. Is this possible??

Comment: Set it `null`..

Comment: Can you try making the required property getter `private`?

Comment: vivek null does not solve the problem. Already tried that! Cant make it private because then it cant be user in Include when querying :-)

Comment: I don't think it auto loads. At least not loading from the database. However if the entity instance with PK equal to the FK of the adding entity is tracked by the context, then the so called navigation property fixup will set the navigation property and will link the tracked entity instances. This is "by design" and cannot be configured/avoided. And should not be a problem at all. Except if we have XY problem here. So why would you need to do what you are asking for?

Comment: THE EF core does not auto-load the properties on add. make sure you set those navigational properties as virtual.

Comment: Cristian they are virtual and on add when you set the Id of the Foreign Key entity (not the instance , only the Id) it is set automatically by EF. We want to be able to set the Id in order to have the reference in the database field but we do not want to set the instance because we have logic in the setters and getters based on the instance and we want it to be null on SaveChanges). I don't know if you can understand the concept... if you need i can provide a use case.

Comment: Add a question mark on the navigation properties. ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ1mz.png)